# In BigQuery suddenly ga_realtime_sessions table is empty. ga_sessions_ table is fine

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Been querying ga_realtime_sessions_ tables just fine for weeks but when I came in after this weekend it says the table is empty. This table is generated by Google as a result of our GA to BigQuery linking settings.

Not sure what to do. ga_sessions_ tables are all fine including the table for yesterday.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FF2C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr92j.png)

Comment: GA service is disrupted. I would contact GA 360 support team

Comment: Yep that was the case. Looks like it was out for about 7 days. Thanks.